# How to set xValuePosition and yValuePosition properly in Pie Chart using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, pie-chart, ios-charts

I am trying to put labels outside properly and lines to point them but the lines are overlapping and labels at the sides are not displayed completely. If length of the line is increased the labels are cut completely.

This is what I'm getting now.
[image]

What I want is
[image]

Code:

```
 `class ViewController: UIViewController{

    let pieView : PieChartView = {
    let set = PieChartView()
    set.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    set.drawHoleEnabled = false
    set.chartDescription?.text = ""  
    return set  
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationItem.title = "Pie"
    setChart()
    chartData()


}

   let surveyData = ["cat": 20, "dog": 30, "both": 5, "neither": 45]

func setChart(){
    view.addSubview(pieView)
    pieView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:    view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    pieView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    pieView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
    pieView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true

}

func chartData(){
    var data = [PieChartDataEntry]()
    for (key,value) in surveyData{

        let entry = PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(value), label: key)
        data.append(entry)
    }
    let chart = PieChartDataSet(values: data, label: "")
    chart.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()
    chart.sliceSpace = 2
    chart.selectionShift = 5
    chart.xValuePosition = .outsideSlice
    chart.yValuePosition = .outsideSlice
    chart.valueTextColor = .black
    chart.valueLineWidth = 0.5
    chart.valueLinePart1Length = 0.2
    chart.valueLinePart2Length = 4
    chart.drawValuesEnabled = true
    let chartData = PieChartData(dataSet: chart)
    pieView.data = chartData
 }}`
```

Comment: Feel free to check my answer and let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your data set:

```
chart.selectionShift = 0
```